# CKEditor in jquery Repeater?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, repeater

I want to use CKEditor in jquery Repeater Control.
Means I want to put CKEditor within Repeater. Within repeater control, I put Text box to put a comment for User. So any suggestions from guys.

Find Text box in every row of a repeater and replace CKEditor with that.

So plz help me out.

```
<div data-repeater-list="">
        
        <div data-repeater-item>
          <textarea class="ckeditor" name="textarea-input">B</textarea>
          <input data-repeater-delete type="button" value="Delete"/>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input data-repeater-create type="button" value="Create Clone"/>
    </form>
    <script src="jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script src="jquery.repeater.js"></script>
        <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        'use strict';

        $('.repeater').repeater({
            defaultValues: {
                'textarea-input': 'foo',
                'text-input': 'bar',
                'select-input': 'B',
                'checkbox-input': ['A', 'B'],
                'radio-input': 'B'
            },
            show: function () {
                $(this).slideDown(function () {
                
                    // create ckeditor Instances
                    
                });
            },
            hide: function (deleteElement) {
                if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this element?')) {
                    $(this).slideUp(deleteElement);
                }
            },
            ready: function (setIndexes) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Show us what you tried and where you are stuck

Comment: done, please check

Comment: Did you try initializing each instance in the `ready` callback?